# Using JavaScript to display a Blob

Tags: javascript, image, base64, blob

I am retrieving a Blob image from a database, and I'd like to be able to view that image using JavaScript. The following code produces a broken image icon on the page:

```
var image = document.createElement('image');
    image.src = 'data:image/bmp;base64,'+Base64.encode(blob);
    document.body.appendChild(image);
```

[Here is a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PDhCy/1/) containing all the code required, including the blob. The completed code should properly display an image.

Comment: What the format of the blob? Is this an image in some format (jpeg, png, gif etc.) or just RGB bytes?

Comment: Should not it be `document.createElement('img');` instead of `document.createElement('image');?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I had hexadecimal data that needed to be converted to binary before being base64encoded.

in PHP:

```
base64_encode(pack("H*", $subvalue))
```

Answer (score 192):

You can also get BLOB object directly from XMLHttpRequest. Setting responseType to blob makes the trick. Here is my code:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "http://localhost/image.jpg");
xhr.responseType = "blob";
xhr.onload = response;
xhr.send();
```

And the response function looks like this:

```
function response(e) {
   var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
   var imageUrl = urlCreator.createObjectURL(this.response);
   document.querySelector("#image").src = imageUrl;
}
```

We just have to make an empty image element in HTML:

```
<img id="image"/>
```

Comment: The important line is the ```urlCreator.createObjectURL(blob)``` which returns a imageUrl which can be assigned to an image src.

Comment: Don't forget to revoke the created URL once you've finished with it by calling; revokeObjectURL

Comment: I'd assume, that OP's image is in some kind of field _in_ a db, i.e. OP can't get it _directly_. If he'd able to do so, he would most likely use an `img` - tag _directly_ instead of doing XHR / fetch; because both are prone to SOP.

Comment: That worked like a charm. Also, IDK why people are not talking about the fact that axios can return blobs by just adding `responseType: 'blob'`. That saved me the hassle of converting anything. Also tested on chrome, both `window.URL` and`window.webkitURL` are truthy

Answer (score 132):

If you want to use fetch instead:

```
var myImage = document.querySelector('img');

fetch('flowers.jpg').then(function(response) {
  return response.blob();
}).then(function(myBlob) {
  var objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(myBlob);
  myImage.src = objectURL;
});
```

Source:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: Will this automatically convert base64 as image is base64 encoded?

Comment: What happens `if (typeof URL !== "function") {}`

Comment: If you vote down please add a comment why. Hard to improve answers otherwise.

Answer (score 31):

You can convert your string into a [Uint8Array](http://www.javascripture.com/Uint8Array) to get the raw data.  Then create a [Blob](http://www.javascripture.com/Blob) for that data and pass to [URL.createObjectURL(blob)](http://www.javascripture.com/URL#createObjectURL) to convert the Blob into a URL that you pass to [img.src](http://www.javascripture.com/HTMLImageElement#src).

```
var data = '424D5E070000000000003E00000028000000EF...';

// Convert the string to bytes
var bytes = new Uint8Array(data.length / 2);

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 2) {
    bytes[i / 2] = parseInt(data.substring(i, i + 2), /* base = */ 16);
}

// Make a Blob from the bytes
var blob = new Blob([bytes], {type: 'image/bmp'});

// Use createObjectURL to make a URL for the blob
var image = new Image();
image.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
document.body.appendChild(image);
```

You can try the complete example at: http://jsfiddle.net/nj82y73d/

Answer (score 19):

In your example, you should `createElement('img')`.

In your link, `base64blob != Base64.encode(blob)`.

This works, as long as your data is valid http://jsfiddle.net/SXFwP/ (I didn't have any BMP images so I had to use PNG).

Comment: Good point on the img. You should note that 'img' is an html image element where 'image' is a html input element of type image, although in this case it did not make a difference.

I am assuming that the image data *is* valid, as it is coming from a 3rd party source. Do you know anyway of testing this? Or an easy site that gives blob from uploaded image? I would like to test BMP's

Comment: The "blob" in your fiddle isn't actually a Blob. You used a base64 encoded string.

Answer (score 13):

I guess you had an error in the inline code of your image.
Try this :

```js
var image = document.createElement('img');
    
image.src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhDwAPAKECAAAAzMzM/////wAAACwAAAAADwAPAAACIISPeQHsrZ5ModrLlN48CXF8m2iQ3YmmKqVlRtW4MLwWACH+H09wdGltaXplZCBieSBVbGVhZCBTbWFydFNhdmVyIQAAOw==";
    
image.width=100;
image.height=100;
image.alt="here should be some image";
    
document.body.appendChild(image);
```

Helpful link :http://dean.edwards.name/my/base64-ie.html

Answer (score 5):

In the fiddle your blob isn't a blob, it's a string representation of hexadecimal data.
Try this on a blob and your done

```
var image = document.createElement('img');
let reader=new FileReader()
reader.addEventListener('loadend',()=>{
  let contents=reader.result
  image.src = contents
  document.body.appendChild(image);
})
if(blob instanceof Blob) reader.readAsDataURL(blob)
```

readAsDataURL give you a base64 encoded image ready for you image element () source (src)