# How to view files sent through x-sendfile as GET response

Tags: php, slim, x-sendfile, slim-3

I am using Slim Framework 3. Here's my code:

```
....
    $response = $response->withStatus(200)
                        ->withHeader('X-Sendfile', $path)
                        ->withHeader('Content-Type', $contentType)
                        ->withHeader('Content-disposition:', 'attachment; filename=' . $fileName);
                    return $response;
....
```

When using through postman, I see the image. But, how do I show the image / video / audio on an html page using the response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the whole file is returned by x-sendfile, the file is actually a **blob**. Hence I set the `responseType` of my ajax request to `blob` in my javascript. I following the answer by @AdamZ here at [Using Javascript to Display Blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650587/using-javascript-to-display-blob) and everything worked.