# Object property returns part of literal

Tags: javascript, angular

I am new to JavaScript Objects and i got a list of object and in that object there is a property called signature which is BLOB, I am trying to decode it so I can display it as image, but when I use it, I am unable to use it.upon debugging in console, the returned item is a number but it has following structure

```
"{
  "signature": "/9j/4AA"
```

but when I do `console.log(typeof + deca);` it says number, following is my code

```
    for (const sign of result){
        const deca = atob(sign.signature);
        console.log(typeof + deca);
```

console.log(deca) I get [this](https://jsfiddle.net/jt5ks76z/)

and using it to display like

```
            <img *ngFor="let sign of selectedUser"
                 [src]="sign.imageData"
                 alt="">
```

Do I need to use trim or slice to cut off the `"{
      "signature":` part or I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

this happens because of the `+` operator, which automatically makes the variable a `number`.

https://jsfiddle.net/n97ssLma/

```js
var test = "test"
alert(typeof test) //string
alert(typeof + test) //number
```

to display your blob as an image do the following:

```js
var image = document.createElement('img');
    
image.src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhDwAPAKECAAAAzMzM/////wAAACwAAAAADwAPAAACIISPeQHsrZ5ModrLlN48CXF8m2iQ3YmmKqVlRtW4MLwWACH+H09wdGltaXplZCBieSBVbGVhZCBTbWFydFNhdmVyIQAAOw==";
    
image.width=100;
image.height=100;
image.alt="here should be some image";
    
document.body.appendChild(image);
```

[Using Javascript to Display Blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650587/using-javascript-to-display-blob/)

updated your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jt5ks76z/1/

example using atob method:

https://jsfiddle.net/jt5ks76z/4/

Comment: Thanks, but my question main part was why do I get signature (object property when I do `atob`, it should just return me a base64 decode,

Comment: I added when I do `console.log(deca)` what do I get. I am using angular.

Comment: in this case please update your question with the code of your TypeScript Class of the relevant component

Comment: It is looping throught a object, and it has property signature.Have a look at my question again/ I explained what is doing on.

Comment: i think you do not get what i said....or i don't get what you are saying. Have a look here: https://jsfiddle.net/jt5ks76z/1/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164416/discussion-between-nofel-and-messerbill).