# Get image from Mysql with NodeJs, Express, EJS

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, ejs

I wanted to get the image from MySQL using NodeJS, and EJS template.
I think the problem is that I failed to transfer buff data into base64.
I have tried many soluction out there but didn't work out. My currect code is ...

**Index.ejs**

```
<% for ( var i = newsData.length -1; i >= 0; i--){ %>
<img src="<%= newsData[i].image %>">
<h3><%= newsData[i].title  %></h3>    //Which is working
<p><%= newsData[i].content %></p>     //Which is working
```

I have tried to use

```
<%- newsData[i].image %>
```

Which give me the result of ...

### [Website show data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pASk3.png)

**routes.js**

```
app.get('/news', isLoggedIn, function({user}, res, next) {

var newsData = '';
db.query('SELECT date,title,content,image FROM news', function(err, rows) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    var newsData = rows;

    // use index.ejs
    res.render('../views/dashboard/html/table/news.ejs', { title: 'Account Information', newsData: newsData, user});

});
```

});

By the way, the image format that I stored in Mysql is "Blob". Thanks

kind regards.

Comment: Refer this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650587/using-javascript-to-display-blob You can't directly use blob.

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<%- newsData[i].image %>"/>
```

Comment: Tried, still give the same result, I assume that my currect newsData.image is not base64 yet, also tried toString but doesn't work out

Comment: What you are getting from db ,can you share your encoded image data

Comment: can you paste the complete value of `<%- newsData[i].image %>` this line