# JSON binaryData Image

Tags: javascript, java, json

Column "picture" in MYSQL have LONGBLOB datatype.
JSON parse image to BLOB. I want to use image in image src=""

```
var selectLapbooks = function () {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", "SelectLapbook", false);
    request.send();
    if (request.status === 200) {
        var response = request.responseText;
        var lapbooks = JSON.parse(response);
        var element = document.getElementById("lapbooks");
        element.innerHTML = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < lapbooks.length; i++) {
            var img = new Image();
            img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([lapbooks[i].picture]));
            element.innerHTML +=
                "<a href='#'><img class='card-img-top' src='"+img.src+"' alt=''></a>";
        }
    }
};
```

[image]

**Data present in picture**

[image]

Comment: Check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650587/using-javascript-to-display-blob

Comment: Add some code of what you have done or what you have tried and go through https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve