# How I display as image a blob object with JS

Tags: javascript, image, blob, web-frontend

My function returns a blob object when I log it in my console:

```
Blob(623853) {name: "profile.jpg", size: 623853, type: "image/jpeg"}
```

I want to display this image to the user with JavaScript, how can I do it?

Comment: you can probably create an img element on the page, and make the src attribute the image path. That should display the image. But you'll need the full path, not sure if 'profile.jpg' is enough. Also see this answer as it has more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650587/using-javascript-to-display-blob

Comment: ı don't know full path of image, image is creating with js using canvas, and convert to blob

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Javascript to Display Blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650587/using-javascript-to-display-blob)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use [URL.createObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) to generate a blob URL and set it as the image source.

```
const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob) // blob is the Blob object
image.src = blobUrl // image is the image element from the DOM
```

Comment: I get: errorReporting: unhandledrejection: TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': Overload resolution failed.

Comment: @YTG The argument passed to the [URL.createObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) method should be a [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob), [`File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File), or [`MediaSource`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSource). Can you share your code?