# Display image fetched from JSON responce in REACT

Tags: reactjs

In my application i need to show multiple images that are loaded from the server on a client side.

This is the server response generating code(ASP.NET Core):

```
    //Create list of thumbnails
    List<Object> thumbnails = new List<Object>();

    foreach (ClosingDocument DItem in PackageConent.Documents)
    {
        DItem.GetPDFDocument();

        Bitmap thumbnail = DItem.GetThumbnailPage(1);

        thumbnails.Add(thumbnail);
    }
    JArray JO = JArray.FromObject(thumbnails);

    response.Add(new JProperty("PdfDocuments", JO));
```

Then on a client side i do
console.log(data.Package.PdfDocuments[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rmlbh.png));

and get the following:
[image]

But how do i convert it into something that i can put into the `<img src="???">`

if i do the following:

```
var dataUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(data.Package.PdfDocuments[1]);
```

> TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function
>   was found that matched the signature provided.

I edited the server code to return Base64 encoded image.

now when i do

```
var blob = atob(data.Package.PdfDocuments[1]);
console.log(blob);
```

i get:

[image]

But when i try to convert in to URL like this:

```
var data = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

i still get:

> TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided.

Thanks!

Comment: I dont see the url or image base64 data in this json

Comment: @victorzadorozhnyy I updated the question to reflect your suggestion

Comment: have a read about canvas https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob#Examples

Comment: and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650587/using-javascript-to-display-blob

Answer (score 0):

The issue I was having was due to the fact that i was trying to convert blob to an URL directly.

What I needed to do was to convert it to the proper file type first like this:

```
var blob = atob(page);
var file = new Blob(this.convertToByteArray(blob), { type: "image/png" });
var imageUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);

convertToByteArray(input) {
    var sliceSize = 512;
    var bytes = [];

    for (var offset = 0; offset < input.length; offset += sliceSize) {
        var slice = input.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);

        var byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);

        for (var i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
            byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
        }

        const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);

        bytes.push(byteArray);
    }

    return bytes;
}
```