# How to get users's photo using Microsoft Graph?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, photo

I have sent a request to Microsoft Graph, to get the photo from the user. 
It looks like this --GET `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/USER_ID/photo/$value`
I get, as a response, binary format of an image, and as doc suggests I made blob object, 
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44nnL.png). 
Type od data(from image) that I recieve, I set to be ng.HttpPromise.

I get url, that I set for image src (in html), but photo isn't showing, and I don't have any Error popped up.

Comment: Could you please wrap your GET request example into backticks '`'  ?

Comment: @MinaRacic, posting screenshots of code is discouraged, could you please include a code sample into a post and update a question in this regard?

Comment: @MinaRacic, .. and maybe provide some details, for instance, what is the type of `data` object, `ArrayBuffer`? regarding  _photo isn't showing_ how the image is getting rendered from  `contact.photoUrl`

Comment: @VadimGremyachev I tried to explain it in more details. Please let me know if everything is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

To get a user's photo using Graph, use: [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7Bid) | userPrincipalName}/photo/$value.
From the sample shared(see below) I can see a minor mistake:
[image: Sample Code]

Once the response completes, you need to call `data.blob()` which returns a promise containing the blob, which you can then pass to `createObjectUrl` after resolution.

```
this.videoEventServie.getPersonPhoto(contact).then(data => {
  return data.blob();

}).then(function(currentBlob){
  var src= URL.createObjectURL(currentBlob);
  myImage.photoUrl = src;
});
```

Please see this answer: [Using JavaScript to display a Blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650587/using-javascript-to-display-a-blob) for additional context.