# How to render a png image from raw binary

Tags: javascript

A rest webservice I'm querying prompts the download modal window when I send a request.
This is the response header

```
{
  "access-control-allow-credentials": "true",
  "access-control-allow-headers": "x-requested-with, content-type, authorization",
  "access-control-allow-methods": "GET, POST, OPTIONS",
  "access-control-allow-origin": "*",
  "connection": "close",
  "content-disposition": "attachment; filename =AR2.png",
  "content-type": "application/octet-stream",
  "date": "Tue, 28 Apr 2020 17:17:18 GMT",
  "server": "Apache-Coyote/1.1",
  "transfer-encoding": "chunked"
}
```

so if I try to `fetch` and print the response body in console I get an unreadable text starting with `\89PNG`, of course.
Is there a way to render the PNG in a html page?
I tried [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) and [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader), but I'm not sure how to use them for this use case.

An attempt I've done

```
var response = // XHR response
var blob = new Blob([response]);
var imageUrl = urlCreator.createObjectURL(blob);
document.querySelector("#image").src = imageUrl;
```

The html page just shows the icon of a broken src where the image should be.

I tried to print the whole `event` (`xhr.onload` callback). `responseType` seems empty.
[image]

Comment: If you're using `fetch` you can get the blob and create a temporary URL to access it in an `<img src`. There's an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44069294/1941241). The same question has an alternative example for if you're using `XMLHttpRequest` instead of `fetch`.

Comment: Actually I use XMLHttpRequest. I tried that version and I get the error `Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided.
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onload`. `createObjectURL` seems to be a static method, so I tried `URL.createObjectURL`, same error.

Comment: Can you add the code with your current attempt? It should be `URL.createObjectURL(theBlobYouHave)` -- that error usually means that whatever you're passing to it is not a Blob or File object.

Comment: Posting the whole code is tricky because the remote request is done by another library. Anyway that's not the point, the library doesn't do any  manipulation of the response in case of `conten-type: application/octet-stream`

Comment: what is the xhr.responseType.  it should be blob

Comment: see edited question. `responseType` seems empty

Comment: set `xhr.responseType = 'blob'` before you make the request

Comment: I'm afraid that would introduce bugs somewhere else, is there no way to convert whatever that thing is in Blob?

Comment: `new Blob([response])` should work

Comment: see edited question, I replaced the code of my previous attempt.

Comment: at minimum you must have: `xhr.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=x-user-defined')`

Answer (score 2):

At minimum you must call this, or you are not getting the binary data.  Without it your request is getting text data only (character set is limited), so it is impossible because of the loss of data.
You have to either change the server-side to return base64 or change the way your XHR request is being made so that you get the binary data:

```js
        xhr.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=x-user-defined');
```

Going from binary string to blob:

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('get','https://i.imgur.com/2T4Vd.png')
  xhr.onload = function(){
   var img = new Image();
   var response = xhr.responseText;
   var binary = new Uint8Array(response.length);
   
   for(var i=0;i<response.length;i++){
    binary[i] = response.charCodeAt(i) & 0xff;
   }
   
   img.src = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([binary.buffer]));
            document.body.appendChild(img)

  }
  xhr.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=x-user-defined');
  xhr.send();
```

Converting to base64

```js
var binary="";
for(var i=0; i<response.length ; i++){
    binary += String.fromCharCode(response.charCodeAt(i) & 0xff);
}

img.src = 'data:image/png;base64,' + btoa(binary);
```

If you are getting an ArrayBuffer, convert ArrayBuffer to Blob:

```js
var blob = new Blob([response]);

var image = URL.createObjectURL( blob );
```

You should be setting the responseType on the XHR request, so that you can get a blob directly.

```js
xhr.responseType = 'blob'
```

You mention the use of `fetch`.  The response object on fetch includes `.blob()` which you would be calling to get a blob object.

```js
const myBlob = await (await fetch('/url')).blob();
```

Comment: As I said in the other comment, I would prefer not changing the library in charge of doing remote request for that, it would introduce bugs in case of other `application/octet-stream` responses. Is there a way to convert in `Blob` the response itself?

Comment: If it's still not working you are getting a `string` result, which will not work.

Comment: To clarify, you are getting a text string with a limited character set and thus there is a loss of data in the response string.

Comment: @alfredopacino in fact, your remote request code shouldn't be working with other `application/octet-stream` responses unless they are also at their base really just purely text files.  There must be a parameter or hook somewhere that allows for requesting binary data.