# Convert binary to blob url

Tags: javascript, html, blob

I have a binary data of a image like 137, 80, 78, 71, 13, 10, 26, 10, 0 as String. I want to display it in  html as blob url. How do i convert the binary to blob url.
I have tries doing these but i am not getting the image.

```js
var binary = "137, 80, 78, 71, 13, 10, 26, 10, 0";
var blob = new Blob([binary], { type: 'image/png' });
var blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

console.log(blobUrl);
document.getElementById("image").src = blobUrl;
```

```html
<img id="image" />
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using JavaScript to display a Blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650587/using-javascript-to-display-a-blob)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to:

1. convert your string to an array of integers,
2. convert that array to a binary string,
3. convert that to base64 and
4. inject that into the `src` attribute of your `<img>`.

```js
var numbers = binary.trim().split(/\s*,\s*/g).map(x => x/1);
var binstr = String.fromCharCode(...numbers);
var b64str = btoa(binstr);
var src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + b64str;
document.getElementById("image").src = src;
```

Bear in mind that you have to use the proper image type, e.g. jpeg, png, etc.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to show the image, you have to do something like this:

```
var binary = "137, 80, 78, 71, 13, 10, 26, 10, 0";
document.getElementById("image").src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + btoa(binary)
```

But I am not sure whether your binary is correct or not.