# How to render an image received in Raw data format?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, base64, encodeuricomponent

I have a React front end application. I am calling an API which is giving me a response of a file image in raw data format, like given below -

```
     �PNG


    IHDR\ ���HiCCPICC ProfileH��WXS��[RIh�H ��"H�B�  U��@B�1!�ؑE�."`CWE] 
    v�eQ��aAee],�Py������w�o��s���̽w�j�T����+ɓŅ�Ʀ��HOt�6�Z<�\ʎ��P����w7�5��.J������  
    �r>H,��9?�}��|�,�7�[O͓*�x�
    |�|����Kѥ�R|)1ee    e3��r��A��Q����ju.��ZO=E�G}���e��5FK�5G�Bk��Y��Zi�4'�6���-�m��ݦ����v�
    ˍ����V�V�VEV���[S���3�WZ�Xw�X،��aSgsǖb�m+�]m{�����]��|�{lw�+٫�׋����v�ۖ�؞�r���/. 
     �`�a�G�g>%z�;�3�s��/�_#�������d<�V�����V�)0.���8�9O%��l�B�?a�YP%��Ûr��9�n8� 7�+��   
    Auw�g����h��C�������|���������&{�cS��K���`C�]7J3?ȿǀ6�nf�     
    pHYs%%IR$��iTXtXML:com.adobe.xmp<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="XMP Core 
    5.4.0">
    <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
      <rdf:Description rdf:about=""
            xmlns:exif="http://ns.adobe.com/exif/1.0/">
         <exif:PixelXDimension>1628</exif:PixelXDimension>
         <exif:PixelYDimension>1056</exif:PixelYDimension>
      </rdf:Description>
    </rdf:RDF>
    </x:xmpmeta>
    �܏�iDOT(��{V6O@IDATx|���I������4F\ڒf$������ޞ��Х����=��pv�*O���鞑9s}�X������.��b�2g    
 N�X�
    �ylC�Pwx'�Ko�����X�e��&�ViP��T�r����G1  �����V��W�
```

My requirement is to show the file in HTML using as simple as

What have I tried -

1. Converted the raw data to base64 and made that the source of the 
   Result - Did not work, since converting it to base64 using btoa itself failed since it has unicode characters.
2. Tried encoding the URI and then base64'ing it based on some solutions on StackOverflow
   Result - Did not work. No error, but the image is not getting rendered.

In short I am trying to set base64 as the  src - "data:image/png;base64,"+btoa(raw data)
and this is clearly not working.

Any working solution or pointer?

Comment: Have you looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650587/using-javascript-to-display-a-blob)? How is the data received? (XMLHttpRequest, fetch, axios)

Comment: @Paul-LouisMas I receive it by using axios to make the REST api call

Comment: Then I think that you can have a look at [this](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/513#issuecomment-292892990), it seems to be the same issue that you have.