# Set Image src from image blob

Tags: javascript

I have trying to request an image from an API and set the src of an `img` in my web page. The API returns a blob that represents a .png file. At this time, I'm requesting the image using the following:

```
const fetchResult = await fetch(imageApiUrl);
const resultBlob = await fetchResult.blob();
console.log(resultBlob);
```

In the console, I can see:

```
Blob {size: [some number], type: "image/png" }
```

So, I know that I have a result. I assume a blob. I now need to set this blob as the source of an `img` in my HTML, which looks like this:

```
<img id="profilePicture" alt="Profile Picture" height="250" width="250" />
```

I have this:

```
var profilePicture = document.getElementById('profilePicture');
```

How do I set the src of the profilePicture element to the blob?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using JavaScript to display a Blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650587/using-javascript-to-display-a-blob)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`URL.createObjectURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) in order to create a temporary URL that points to the in-memory image:

```
let url = URL.createObjectURL(resultBlob);

const img = document.getElementById('profilePicture');
img.src = url;
```