# Get Image size (not dimension) inside image tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, image, filesize

I have an `<img>` tag which is filled with dynamic `src` attribute. I would like to display the image size (in bytes) upon image load using javascript/jQuery.

I tried using the below. But, it returns zero in all 3 properties.

```
$('#img').on('load',
                function() {
                    var imgUrl = $(this).attr("src");
                    var imgPerf = performance.getEntriesByName(imgUrl)[0];
                    console.log(Math.round(imgPerf.decodedBodySize)); // returns 0
                    console.log(Math.round(imgPerf.encodedBodySize)); // returns 0
                    console.log(Math.round(imgPerf.transferSize)); // returns 0
                });
```

Is there any other possible ways to get the image size value?

FYI, the images are loaded from different domain.

Comment: The problem with "image size" is that it will depend on the compression, so the *file* size and the *image* size are not always the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

if you have image url you can try this:

```
const fileImg = await fetch(URL_TO_IMG).then(r => r.blob());
```

This will get the resource through HTTP and then returns the full binary as a blob object, then you can access its properties including its size in bytes as:

```
fileImg.size
```

Comment: You can also use this to only load the image once (rather than use `src=` to have the browser load it then re-load it to get the size) - see : https://stackoverflow.com/a/44069294/2181514