# how to fetch images form amazon s3

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, fetch

i'm trying to get image blob data via amazon api :

```
        const url = "https://ayae52i9de.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/s3?key=elephant-trax/google_103236758783646644108/01232022112248_69365b28-43e0-406f-a0ce-8e6716146f61";
```

here is js code :

```
const options = {method: 'GET'};

fetch('https://ayae52i9de.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/s3?key=elephant-trax%2Fgoogle_103236758783646644108%2F01232022112248_69365b28-43e0-406f-a0ce-8e6716146f61', options)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(response => console.log(response))
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

[image]

please tell me how show images at our web page in html js

Comment: Check this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/44069294/2978985

Comment: Why not just `<img src="<url here>">` ?

Comment: i have tryied to set url at img src but its not woking, you can check at your system .